# Apache (httpd.exe) process CPU and Memory utilization causing slow or non-responsive web pages

Tags: php, apache

ISSUE: My website is extremely slow processing pages, and often times just hangs.

OLD environment: I used to run Apache 2.2 (from Apachelounge), PHP 5.3, and MySQL 5.5 on a Windows 2008 Web Server phyical box, hosted by Peer1 (ServerBeach).  Website ran fast and reliable.  At the time, I was using "mysql_*" commands versus "mysqli_*".

NEW environment: I now have a google compute engine VM running Windows Server 2012 R2.  I installed Apache 2.4 from apachehaus.com (httpd-2.4.12-x64-vc11-r2.zip), PHP 5.6.9 (VC11 x64 Thread Safe), and MySQL 5.6.25 (64 bit).  With some tweaking to the new httpd.conf and vhosts.conf files, I got my website back up and running.  I also converted all the mysql_* references successfully to mysqli_*.  Here's what I'm noticing:  If I pull up the task manager on the apache server and watch the httpd process, every time I navigate to a website page, the CPU process climbs drastically and slowly gets back down to 0%.  Often times, it'll even hit between 95-100% CPU utilization and stay there for a good 5 seconds, before slowly getting back down to 0%.  Also, the apache memory utilization keeps getting larger with every page request, and never goes down.  The website and mysql calls work and pages display fine, it just takes a long time to process.

I believe this to be a PHP issue, but I could be wrong.  Recommendations are welcome.

Comment: So is your new VM equal to the old environment in terms of processing power?

Comment: No, the new VM has double the memory and almost double the processing power.

Comment: Measure response times with a tool like apache benchmark or siege, this will give you a good idea of how your server is handling the load

Comment: Memory usage steadily going up means memory leaks. That's something _very_ hard to debug in Apache HTTPD + PHP. Where is the server located? You have to choose where it's physically located so that you avoid latency issues.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I experience this issue even opening the web page on the hosted server's browser.

Comment: Is it slow after some time or right from the beginning after a restart? If it's the former then it's caused by memory leaks. If not then something you changed runs slower _or_ GCE is slower. There's a change the resources allocated on your VM are not absolute - meaning not available instantly and for long periods of time - that's usually the case with VMs.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv It *seems to get slower the more it gets accessed, and I know already (due to the memory utilization always incrementing and never going down) that there's a memory leak.  Yes, VM's resources are not always constant and are pretty much supply/demand so that too could play a factor.  I'll try to duplicate my old server '08 setup this weekend and see if that will yield any 'ah-ha' moments.  I'll post back with my results.  Thanks for watching and replying!

Comment: Okay, I uninstalled the apache 2.4 service.  I restored a backup of apache and php files from the old server (apache 2.2, php 5.4.41, all 32 bit stuff).  Same exact issue.  Memory would always go up and never down, and httpd.exe process kept spiking CPU utilization on every new page request.  So... that rules out quite a few things.  I'm stumped.  Could it be the VM as opposed to a physical box?  I don't know how being on a VM would affect httpd.exe process spiking and memory leaks.